# Issue with DNS and subdomains

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, virtualhost, ubuntu

I have an Apache running on an Ubuntu Server (14.04). I've configured the DNS A records and VH in order to have one domain and two subdomains just like this:

> - example.com
> - subdomain1.example.com
> - subdomain2.example.com

Everything is running ok, but the problem is that when I try to access to my website by the server ip, the browser shows subdomain1.example.com content instead of example.com content. This is not happening if I type example.com, in this case everything goes ok, but I'm worried if this could be a problem in the future or if I've done something wrong...

Here is my Apache VH config for example.com and subdomain1.example.com (subdomain2 is exactly like subdomain1):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAdmin contact@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined 
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain1.example.com
    ServerAdmin contact@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain1

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined 
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope I've explained well...
Thank you!

Comment: are all virtualhost configs in the same .conf file?

Comment: nope, they are in different .conf files, sorry for not mention it before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#virtualhost)

> When a request is received, the server first maps it to the best
>   matching  based on the local IP address and port
>   combination only. Non-wildcards have a higher precedence. If no match
>   based on IP and port occurs at all, the "main" server configuration is
>   used.
>
> If multiple virtual hosts contain the best matching IP address and
>   port, the server selects from these virtual hosts the best match based
>   on the requested hostname. If no matching name-based virtual host is
>   found, then the first listed virtual host that matched the IP address
>   will be used. As a consequence, the first listed virtual host for a
>   given IP address and port combination is the default virtual host for
>   that IP and port combination.

This basicaly means that first VirtualHost encountered in `httpd.conf` will be used as default, or if all Virtual Hosts are in separate (included) `.conf` files (which is probably your case), then the one from alphabetically first `.conf` file will be used.

TLDR: try renaming the `.conf` file containing the `example.com` Virtual Host to `aaa.conf` (and restart httpd)

Comment: Good catch, this is almost certainly the issue. @NeoSennin, what you probably want to do is handle requests to the IP address differently. For that, create one more VirtualHost entry and store it in, say, `0-default.conf` in the same directory as the others, or in your `httpd.conf` before the `include` line.

Comment: Amazing! it was exactly that. Issue fixed, thanks so much!